# Darlington array: How to output desired voltage at uln2803a driver colectors?

Tags: relay, circuit-design, driver, darlington, active-components

Someone suggested this driver array to get the current I need:
[datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf)
I also need a 12V signal and about a current of 100mA in order to control a relay coil. My 12V signal would come from a logic gate that will provide a current of I = 10mA. So here is where I need the driver. But I need to keep 12V at the driver outputs.

This is my first time working with this kind of device. 
Reading datasheet I don't understand how to get Vout = 12V. It says that Vout = VCE and max rate is 50V. But it also says that Icoil = (V coil supply - VCE(sat))/Rcoil. So I don't know if VCE must be VCE(sat).

My questions:

1. Is V coil supply the desired VCE voltage at the output? Must I do
   something in order to keep Vout = 12V when I apply Vin = 12V = VBase?
2. By the way, what must I do in order to keep the colector current
   that coils are needing?
3. "The collector current rating of each darlington pair is 500mA" --> 500mA per channel, is it?

Comment: It looks like you're completely focused on the ULN2803 since someone recommended it to you. To me it is **unclear** why you would need to use the ULN2803. You should take a "step back" and **describe what the circuit needs to do** I mean: how many relays? What current does the relay coil need? If there's only one relay (or two) there are much simpler solutions than using an ULN2803.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have NOR and NAND gates that controls 8 relays. They have 80mA of consumption when Vcoil = 12V and they wil be active. When 0, they will be open. The problem is that gates output gives only 10mA. I was needing how to handle those output signals for giving the needed current to the coils. This is the post where the driver was suggested and the situation: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447828/logic-gates-for-relay-coils-analogic-control-signals/447834#447834

Comment: It is a Darlington and at the current you mentioned for the relay coil you will lose a volt with this IC. Its outputs are open collector NPN, so this means the relay must be connected between your 12 V supply and an output pin. The output pins themselves don't source 12 V.

Comment: Thanks @jonk I think I start to understand. But is it ok if Vin (VB) is 12V? I need to reproduce Vin voltages at coil, but giving them the amplified current. But I also need to replicate Vin = 0 at Vout (coil). Could it works adding the 12V supply as you say?

Comment: The inputs are designed for about 5 V or less. You probably should insert a series resistor of 5.6 kOhm or higher if you are using 12 V to drive the inputs. The inputs only need 250 microamps, or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reading datasheet I don't understand how to get Vout = 12V.

You need a 12 volt power supply capable of supplying the various load currents. The ULN2803 doesn't magically produce 12 volts without a power supply and even then, its outputs are either "on" (conducting to ground) or "off" (open circuit). It has what is known as "open collector" outputs and you insert the load between a collector and the 12 volts (from the power supply). The negative end of the 12 volt power supply connects to pin 9 of the ULN2803.

You need an input of about 3 volts or higher to activate the channel of the ULN2803 you are connecting your load to.

Comment: Thanks @Andy aka Must I also connect 12V to the COM pin in order to get VOH = 12V? I have seen this at datasheet example.

Comment: @EugeniaSuarez the COM pin is used when the load you drive is inductive and the internal diodes vent the stored energy to any component on the COM pin. This means that COM can connect to the 12 volt power rail to return inductive energy to the power supply or, you can use a zener diode from COM to ground (for instance).

Answer (score 4):

On page 9 of the datasheet you linked, you can find this very convenient example of a single gate found in the ULN2803A:

[image]

This is an NPN Darlington arrangement. (You really should become familiar with it, if you aren't already. The usual behavioral example will have the two BJTs arranged that way but may not include all those diodes and resistors.) The left NPN drives the right NPN and it's not uncommon to hear the right NPN called the ***output*** BJT and the left NPN called the ***driver*** BJT. Regardless, the effect is that for switching relatively high BJT collector-to-emitter currents, the ***output*** BJT will need substantial excess base current and one way to help do that is to add the left side BJT so that it can supply that substantial excess base current while itself requiring far less base current.

That was a long sentence at the end. So put more quickly, imagine the right BJT will can handle \$250\:\text{mA}\$ as the output current. But to do that, it needs \$10\:\text{mA}\$ of base current (as a hypothetical.) To further reduce that need, the left BJT is added. It can deliver \$10\:\text{mA}\$ to the right BJT, but it will only need, say, \$1\:\text{mA}\$ of base current. So combining the two means \$\frac1{10}\$th what otherwise might be needed for base drive current. That can be an advantage worth the trouble, at times.

One thing that is very important for this particular buffered inverter gate is that since it uses NPN BJTs and since the emitter side is tied to the lowest voltage (ground), the output cannot ever source current. It can only sink current. This means that it cannot drive \$12\:\text{V}\$ -- instead, when it is active, it actively drives \$1\:\text{V}\$ or so. (Not \$0\:\text{V}\$ because the two BJTs use up [or require, to operate] about one volt. So you can't affect that. You have to accept the loss of it.) Another way of saying this is that the output can sink current, but that in doing so the output voltage rises upward away from ground by about a volt. This is NOT a good thing. It's just a necessary evil with this circuit. You can see this effect in the datasheet:

[image]

In your case, for \$I_\text{C}=100\:\text{mA}\$ (the top row) note that the typical value (middle column) shows \$0.9\:\text{V}\$ and that the worst case (right column) shows \$1.1\:\text{V}\$. (They don't show a minimum, not because it doesn't exist, but because as a designer you don't care about best cases. You want to know about worst cases, so you can plan for them.)

Above the first diagram I included here, read the following text:

[image]

Note that they tell you straight up that the inputs are designed for something between \$3.3\:\text{V}\$ and \$5.0\:\text{V}\$. You could probably directly use those voltages at the inputs. (Note the \$2.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor in the diagram, which will help limit the base drive currents? That's selected for those voltages.)

But if you want to use higher voltages to drive the input, this is a warning to think more. So let's go back to another part of that datasheet row I'd earlier mentioned. So you see that it mentions \$I_\text{I}=250\:\mu\text{A}\$? Well, that's the input current they need to meet the specifications they gave you. That's what you want to target.

Before jumping straight into that, let's take a look at another piece of the datasheet:

[image]

Here, the closest row to your case is for \$I_\text{C}=200\:\text{mA}\$. Note that the worst case is \$V_{I\left(\text{ON}\right)}=2.4\:\text{V}\$? This includes the drop across those resistors you saw, earlier. But it gives you an idea about what kind of series "limiting" resistor you will want to add to the circuit before applying \$12\:\text{V}\$ as a driving voltage to the input. We can compute this added series resistor as \$R=\frac{12\:\text{V}-2.4\:\text{V}}{250\:\mu\text{A}}=38.4\:\text{k}\Omega\$. That's the largest value you should consider. And if you wanted to make certain that you delivered more than they appear to request in the specification, say \$1\:\text{mA}\$, then \$R=\frac{12\:\text{V}-2.4\:\text{V}}{1\:\text{mA}}=9.6\:\text{k}\Omega\$. I'd recommended ***at least*** \$5.6\:\text{k}\Omega\$ in earlier comments, just to be sure. But I think you could safely use \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and be fine.

The point here is that you look over the datasheet and try and pick out little details to help you think and to work out some kind of idea about how it works and to bracket the range of behavior so that you can decide if you need to add something and, if so, what kind of something to add.

The final circuit might look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSAe2I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that you won't expect a full \$12\:\text{V}\$ across the relay coil. But most relays can operate at about 70% of their rated voltage. So I think this will be okay. Also note that I've been assuming you will be using \$+12\:\text{V}\$ as the active voltage of your control line. If you use a different voltage there, be sure to adjust the resistor value per the logic I gave above. Also, note that there is a lot of flexibility in the exact resistor value. So, you can feel some freedom to adjust its value to something you have on hand. Just don't make it too small or too large.

---

Jasen mentioned in a comment below that I'd neglected to discuss the diodes associated with the **COM** lead of the ULN2803A package. It's worth a short note. Since the ULN2803A is designed with the idea of driving relays and motors (among other things), which can possess substantial inductance, some pathway is needed to allow the stored magnetic energy to dissipate when the gate becomes inactive (and cannot provide a path.) One of the three indicated diodes is tied from the open collector output to the **COM** line for this purpose. This diode is called a "flyback" diode and usually tied to the positive rail voltage to which one side of the relay coil is also tied. When the gate is active (the relay coil is pulsed on or turned on, this flyback diode should be reverse-biased (simple inspection is usually enough to note this fact.) When the gate becomes inactive, the coil current will continue in the same direction but will start to decline as the relay coil suddenly forward-biases the flyback diode allowing its coil current to pass through the flyback diode while it declines back to zero.

If this diode were not present and no other alternative managed paths provided (snubbers, for example), then the relay coil voltage would still reverse itself but that voltage likely would be much larger -- enough so that the current would be able to find some unexpected/unmanaged path. It is much better to provide a managed path and this diode helps achieve that. (One might add additional components if a faster relay coil release is desired, though.)

The diodes from ground to the gate input and/or gate output is there to cover some typical drive cases where some capacitance might otherwise drive these pin voltages well below ground for a short moment. Providing the diodes allows such capacitance an "easy" path to discharge while also keeping the pins from falling too far below ground (limiting it to about one diode drop below ground and usually only for a very short time.)

Comment: lots of good detail there, you only omitted how to use the common pin to protect against back-emf.

Comment: @Jasen I just didn't believe the OP was ready for that extra bit, so neglected it. But upon more reflection, I guess I should add that bit. I'll get to it. Thanks.

Comment: maybe just add a note that by connecting COM to +12V you get the diode in the chip in parallel with the relay coil, so that you don't need an external diode in that position.

Comment: Oh @jonk I really appreciate your detailed explanation I have just learnt a lot. Thanks very much. But I'm missing something because I don' t understand it: When VB = 0V, TRT are off. So: 1) how can C be HIGH and 2) how much HIGH (what voltage value) and why? from where/what node does C take this high voltage?

Comment: @Eugenia In that case, "C" is "open" and isn't actively driven to any voltage value. You could use a resistor tied high, if you wanted to do that and if so then the voltage at "C" would be pulled towards whatever voltage the other end of the resistor was tied towards. Think of it as a switch with one end tied to ground. If closed, the other end of the switch is tied hard to ground. But if open? It's tied to nothing at all.

Comment: Hi @jonk, thanks, in that case (VB = 0V) I would really like to have the coil off (no active relay). I don't know what else may I need for this. Maybe if C is open, negative coil terminal is open and it is the same as coil being off.

Comment: @Eugenia If you tie one end of the coil to your higher voltage source needed by the coil and tie the other end to "C", then that should work. When the input is low, the circuit will be like an open switch and no current can flow in the coil. Sure, "C" will be pulled high by the coil. But that merely means there is no voltage across the coil. So it won't engage. If the input is high, however, then the circuit actively pulls that end on the coil to ground causing the coil to activate.

Comment: Ok! @jonk it has been useful.

Comment: @junk I have just thought about one more thing. Is it a problem or a Vip fact to take into account if control line incomming from a logic gate output is giving 10mA? Ii is physically = Iout node I understand that Ii will be 10mA, but driver only needs 240uA. Must I recalculate the ressistor value?

Comment: Or is 250 uA only a minimum value? Here says that Ii max = 1.3mA, but in the case of using VCE = 2V.

Comment: @EugeniaSuarez The \$250\:\mu\text{A}\$ value is probably a typical figure (I'm a hobbyist, so I'll bow to experts that may differ on this point.) This means it may require more or less. It would be safer to double or quadruple the value (I used \$1\:\text{mA}\$ for my calculations.) Your I/O pin should be fine. Note that your I/O pin does NOT ***force*** current. It simply ***complies*** with what the circuit requests and with what it is capable of handling. (Not sure if I understood your questions, though. So I may have missed the mark in trying.)

Answer (score 3):

> Is V coil supply the desired VCE voltage at the output? Must I do something in order to keep Vout = 12V when I apply Vin = 12V = VBase?

ULN2803a is an inverter, a high input causes a low output. For loads smaller than 200mA, 2.4V is sufficient on the input. 12V on the input will not cause problems.

> By the way, what must I do in order to keep the colector current that coils are needing?

Connect the other end of the coil to a 12 volt supply. ULN2803 connects the outputs to ground when the inputs are high. it does not by itself source current or provide voltage on the output

> "The collector current rating of each darlington pair is 500mA" --> 500mA per channel, is it?

Yes, but performance is only guaranteed at 300mA.  There's also a 2.5A total current limit, but if you stick to 300mA that won't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks @Jasen, if I put 12V supply side connected to coil + terminal and -terminal to the collector (GND when Vin = high) pin; coil will be polarized, is it? But when Vin = low, what happens with coil terminal connected to the collector pin? What will be the voltage level at collector?

Comment: When low the gate turns off and the pin is not driven (like a switch that is off), with the coil connected current through the coil will make the pin high.